# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de definir una variable en python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

Tengo una duda, ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de definir una variable en python3? Me refiero si es correcto definirla empezando con una mayúscula, así:

Mayúscula:

```
self.Var = 1
Variable = 1
```

O Minúscula:

```
self.varInt = 1
variable = 1
```

Y también, ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de definir variables de control, StringVar, IntVar, etc?

¿Es correcto definirla con `self.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` se utiliza únicamente para definir variables de clases, de manera que se queden almacenadas en la misma. Esto es un concepto muy genérico de la programación orientada a objetos. Así que si dudas al respecto, busca tutoriales de clases de Python.

```
ClaseDePrueba():
  __init__(self):
    self.pepinos = 3

  funcion1(self):
    self.patatas = 1

  funcion2(self):
    platanos = 2
```

Con ese código, podríamos acceder a las variables de la siguiente manera:

```
clase_instanciada = ClaseDePrueba()
print(clase_instanciada.pepinos)
print(clase_instanciada.patatas)
print(clase_instanciada.platanos)
```

Veremos los `prints` de pepinos y patatas, pero platanos va a fallar. Al no ser una variable de la clase (por no tener el `self`) platanos se convierte en una variable temporal de la función, es decir, que solo existe mientras se ejecuta la función, pero no se queda guardada en la clase.

Respecto a StringVar, IntVar, etc, olvidate de eso en Python. Es un lenguaje interpretado donde poner `algo = "una string de prueba"` simplemente funciona. No hace falta decirle al programa qué es cada cosa, salvo que especificamente querramos hacer cosas muy complejas que puedan ser confusas, como operaciones con numeros `float` e `integros` y tengas que estar transformando datos, etc.

Respecto a si mayúscula o minúscula, se aconseja minusculas y barra baja para separar palabras. Esto se ve en el standard de estilo de python, PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: Un detalle de nomenclatura, por ser rigurosos. Las variables que asignas mediante `self` se deben llamar en realidad "atributos de objeto", o si quieres se puede permitir "variables de objeto", pero nunca variables de clase ya que eso son otra cosa. Las variables (o atributos) de clase pertenecen a la propia clase y no a ningún objeto instanciado a partir de ella.

Answer (score 2):

Sobre self no intervengo porque Saelyth lo ha dejado bastante claro.

**Acerca de las mayúsculas y minúsculas al iniciar una variable:**

Es cierto que siendo Python un lenguaje interpretado no hay reglas al respecto, pero es importante tener una forma precisa de hacer las cosas y mantenerla en todo momento para que el código sea legible con mayor facilidad por otros o por ti mismo si lo necesitas después de algún tiempo.

Acá te dejo unos ejemplos de como yo suelo hacerlo:

```
variable = "variable que cambiará su valor"  # todo en minúsculas
VARIABLE = "variable constante que nunca cambiará su valor"  # todo en mayúsculas
Llamar_Variable()  # primeras letras en mayúscula
```

Tu puedes hacerlo de la manera que más te guste.